# Can tab refer to other context element(panel) instead of the tab's context when I use jQuery UI 1.9 Tabs

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to use jQuery UI 1.9 Tabs like this way:

**HTML**：

```
<!-- this is the tab's context -->
<div id="tabs">
    <ul id="tabs-ul">
        <li id="tabs-email"><a href="#Email" title="Email">Email</li>
        <li id="tabs-setting"><a href="#Settings" title="Settings">Setting</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- this is the other context -->
<div id="Email">someting</div>
<div id="Settings">someting</div>
```

**JS**：

```
$("#tabs").tabs({});
```

When I do like blow and click one tab,there will be :

```
Uncaught Error: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier.
```

What I want is the tab(`"li#tabs-email"/"li#tabs-setting"`) can automatic refers to the other div context's panel(`"div#Email"/"div#Settings"`).But I can't find the way to change panel context.What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without significant work. Mainly because the whole "globalPanels" thing is semantically wrong, and is why it's been removed.

The way it works now means that all tab content is implicitly related to the tabs.

Comment: Thank you.Fortunately,I changed the way to perform the "globalPanels" thing.Do you mean the "globalPanels" thing is illogical?